# Isolated scope faied to pass object to its main controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/pudv35c0/3/

I want to create a directive with week days that you can select(click on)
and update the rootscope with the new "week"( selected day in the new week object)

when you click on "Add" button then the selected days on the first row will be deleted and a new record will be added to the top of shiftlist.
I created  jsfiddle:

my problem is I create a new scope in the new directive (weekDays) which suppose to move the week object(with the selected days) to its root scope method, but week is null when the method is called

weekdays directive:

```
app.directive("weekDays", function(){
  return{
    restrict: "AEC",
     scope: {
      shiftPatterns: '=',
      action: '&'
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
       $scope.week = [{"name":"MON", "selected":false}  , {"name":"TUE", "selected":false}  , {"name":"WED", "selected":false}  , {"name":"THU", "selected":false} , {"name":"FRI", "selected":false}  , {"name":"SAT", "selected":false}  , {"name":"SUN", "selected":false} ];
       $scope.AddOrRemoveDay = function(day){
          day.selected = !day.selected
      };

    },
    template: "<div style='width:500px; display:inline'>"+
                "<div ng-repeat='day in week' ng-class=\"{true:'possibleDayStyle', false:'notPossibleDay'}[day.selected]\" ng-click='AddOrRemoveDay(day)'>"+
                    "{{day.name}}</div>"+
                "</div>"+
                "<button class='btnAddPossibleDays' ng-click='action(week)'>Add</button>"
  }
});



app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.shiftPatterns = [];
  $scope.name="or";
  shiftPatternObj = function(week){
    this.title = $scope.title;
    this.minDays = $scope.minDays;
    this.maxDays = $scope.maxDays;
    this.selectedDays =  angular.copy(week);
    //this.selectedDays =  angular.copy($scope.week);
  }

  $scope.AddShift = function(week){
    var objShift = new shiftPatternObj();
    $scope.shiftPatterns.push(objShift);

    $scope.cleanShiftValues();
  }

  $scope.cleanShiftValues = function(){


    this.title = "";
    this.minDays = 0;
    this.maxDays = 0;
  }

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pudv35c0/3/

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to pass `week` into `new shiftPatternObj()` in `AddShift` function?

Comment: I didnt forget you cam see my code

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new shiftPatternObj(week)` instead of `new shiftPatternObj()`?

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<week-days action="AddShift(week)" ...
```

*You forgot it on the `week-days` above the `ng-repeat`.*

In directive's template:

```
... ng-click='action({ week: week })' ...
```

Comment: can i changed the week value? I mean is it pass by value or by refernce?, I would like to change the week value

Comment: What do you mean with `change the week value`? It is an array. Do you want to pass another array?

Comment: There is no "pass by reference" available in JavaScript. References to objects are passed by value. There are plenty of information available regarding this if you find it confusing (which you shouldn't feel bad about if you do).